# Laravel Echo.js not receiving notification from pusher no log message

Tags: laravel, events, websocket, notifications, broadcast

I followed up some tutorials about echo and pusher. I configured all the project as necessary but object notifications not appear at browser. I uncoment the line

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class RegisterNewNotification extends Notification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['broadcast'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
                'message' => $this->message,
            ];
    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'message' => $this->message,
        ]);
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Admin.{adminId}', function ($admin, $adminId) {
    return $admin->id === $adminId;
});
```

```
Route::get('noti',function(){

    $user = Admin::first();
    $user->notify(new RegisterNewNotification("Hello"));

});
```

```
        <script type="module">

        Echo.private('App.Models.Admin.1')
            .notification((notification) => {
                console.log(notification.message); // no log
            });



//Echo.channel('events').listen('NewUserRegister', (e) => console.log("RealTimeEventMessage: "+e.message));
        </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWEA9.png)

I followed up some tutorials about echo and pusher. I configured all the project as necessary but object notifications not appear at browser. I uncoment the line

Comment: Are you actually running the queue? If you don’t want to use the queue you should implement the `ShouldBroadcastNow` interface in your notification